# Write Test Class for ContentDocument Trigger that sends email notification

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, email, contentdocument

I have the below code that fires an email notification to 3 related users from the account of the user that uploaded a document (this is for experience cloud users only). I'm struggling to get started on writing the test class.

Questions:

1. the document needs to be created by a user that has checkbox 'Is_Portal_User__c' = TRUE and is an experience cloud user so that the accountID field on User object is populated. do i have to create new users in test class or can i use existing user?
2. 3 user fields needs to be populated on account, same question as above should i create new users in class or use existing?
3. how should i create contentDocument in test class?

Trigger:

```
trigger ContentDocumentTrigger on ContentDocument (after insert) {
        switch on Trigger.operationType{
        
        when AFTER_INSERT {
            ContentDocumentTriggerHandler.emailNotif(Trigger.new);
        }
    
    }
}
```

Trigger Handler:

```
public class ContentDocumentTriggerHandler {
        public static void emailNotif( List<ContentDocument> listCD){
            Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity(5);
            String[] notificationList = new String[] {};
            List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> allmsg = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            List<ContentDocument> notifList = new List<ContentDocument>(); 
            Set<Id> userList = new Set<Id>();
            String createdByName = '';
            
            // Query all portal users
            Set<Id> portalUsers = new Set<Id>();
            for(user u : [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Is_Portal_User__c = TRUE]){
                portalUsers.add(u.Id);
                system.debug('*******************************' + portalUsers);
            }
            
            // check creator is portal user - add to notifList - print records in notifList
            for(ContentDocument test: listCD){
                if(portalUsers.contains(test.CreatedById)){
                    notifList.add(test);
                    userList.add(test.CreatedById);
                    system.debug(test); 
                    system.debug(userList);
                }
               
            }      
            
            for(User userInfo : [SELECT Id,Full_Name__c, AccountID, Account.Name, Account.Assigned_Closer_Coverage_Email__c, Account.Assigned_Oppty_Coverage_Email__c, Account.Account_Owner_Email__c FROM User WHERE Id IN :userList]){
                if(userInfo.Account.Assigned_Closer_Coverage_Email__c != NULL){
                    notificationList.add(userInfo.Account.Assigned_Closer_Coverage_Email__c);
                }
                if(userInfo.Account.Assigned_Oppty_Coverage_Email__c != NULL){
                    notificationList.add(userInfo.Account.Assigned_Oppty_Coverage_Email__c);
                }
                if(userInfo.Account.Account_Owner_Email__c != NULL){
                    notificationList.add(userInfo.Account.Account_Owner_Email__c);
                }
                createdByName = userInfo.Full_Name__c;
                system.debug('**********************************' + notificationList);
                
                
            }      
           
                      
            
            // create email message        
                for(ContentDocument c: notifList){
                    
                   
                    mail.setToAddresses(notificationList);
                    mail.setSubject('Document Upload Notification');
                    system.debug('********************************' + c);
                    mail.setHtmlBody('Document:<b> ' + c.Title +' </b>has been created by ' + createdByName +'.<p>'+
         'To view document <a href=ORGLINK'+c.Id+'>click here.</a>');
                    allmsg.add(mail);       
                    
            }
            system.debug('*************************To Addresses*********************' + mail.toaddresses);
                Messaging.sendEmail(allmsg);
    }
}
```